# DSR, OLSR and ZRP simulation problems in NS2

Tags: ns2

I am trying to simulate each type of routing protocoles in NS2. I started with AODV and DSDV, it worked very well, but when I tried to simulate DSR I got this error "core dumped", and for OLSR and ZRP I got this one:

```
    (_o16 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o16 cmd addr"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o16" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"_o16 addr"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $node addr $args"
    ("default" arm line 2)
    invoked from within
"switch -exact $routingAgent_ {
DSDV {
set ragent [$self create-dsdv-agent $node]
}
DSR {
$self at 0.0 "$node start-dsr"
}
AODV {
set ragent [$self cre..."
    (procedure "_o3" line 14)
    (Simulator create-wireless-node line 14)
    invoked from within
"_o3 create-wireless-node"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $self create-wireless-node $args"
    (procedure "_o3" line 23)
    (Simulator node line 23)
    invoked from within
"$ns_ node"
    ("for" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"for {set i 0} {$i < $opt(nn) } {incr i} {
set node_($i) [$ns_ node]
$node_($i) random-motion 0 ;# disable random motion
}"
    (file "zrp.tcl" line 110)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

AODV and DSR are default applications in ns2.

ZRP can be added to ns-2.35 with the patch [zrp-ns235.patch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNNUVuOE9MQWhRNTQ/view?usp=sharing) ... Build examples, post #22 [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-install-zrp-zone-routing-protocol-patch-in-ns-2-35-a-918489/page2.html) and post 9/8/15 [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ns-users/JJVNvTnAdXY)

OLSR can be added to the ZRP patched ns-2.35 with [umolsr_for-zrp-patched_ns235.patch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSnM3MlhSUXNEZ0E/view?usp=sharing)

Valid simulation examples:

1. OLSR: [umolsr-examples-05.2016.tar.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNWXlHRmxQV0hpWXM/view?usp=sharing)
2. ZRP: [zrp-examples-05.2016.tar.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNcmwzWVNjai1oaWc/view?usp=sharing)

     -